# When should I return?

Tags: php, oop

I am struggling to create an access object to sections stored in the Database. This is a skellington of the process, this contains static data until I can get the principle working.

```
class User {
    const IS_ADMIN = 1;
    const IS_MODERATOR = 2;
    const IS_MEMBER = 4;
}
```

This class will auto-load data from the database eventually but for the time being, this class has default values.

```
class Scope {
    private $priv = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->priv = [1];
    }

    public function getPrivilidges() {
        return $this->priv;
    }
}
```

This is where it messes up, I can tell that the second and third conditions cannot be met if the first fails, how can I stop this?

```
class Priverlidges {
    public function canView($type, Scope $scope) {
        if($type & User::IS_ADMIN) {
            foreach($scope->getPrivilidges() as $p) {
                if($p == User::IS_ADMIN) continue;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        if($type & User::IS_MODERATOR) {
            foreach($scope->getPrivilidges() as $p) {
                if($p == User::IS_MODERATOR) continue;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        if($type & User::IS_MEMBER) {
            foreach($scope->getPrivilidges() as $p) {
                if($p == User::IS_MEMBER) continue;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage which works fine when the default value of the priverlidge is 1:

```
echo (int)(new Priverlidges)->canView(User::IS_ADMIN, new Scope());
```

Example usage which works fine when the default value of the priverlidge is 2:

```
echo (int)(new Priverlidges)->canView(User::IS_MODERATOR | User::IS_ADMIN, new Scope()); // it returns false at the first condition
```

Can anyone help me with when to return true or false? Thanks in advance. 
P.S - Users can be both Mods and Admins

EDIT: I have tried to use `in_array()` and still am unsure when to return the value `true` or `false` because it get's overwrite if the second method runs.

Comment: I don't quite understand the desired logic. Do you want to skip a check for a `User` constant, if it doesn't exist in `$scope->getPrivilidges()`?

Comment: Its an RBAC controller, each role has access scopes to a permissions table. Since there are only, and will only be, 3 user groups. I just hard coded the groups. The code (will eventually) query the permissions in the `Scope` object and then a developer can easily check if the user has permissions to controllers/views. For example, the MOD control panel. But of course, this still needs to be altered because there are read, write and edit scopes. @RuslanOsmanov

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First, check the user is not already authenticated using a placeholder (`$this->_state`). Then check the type of user and check it is inside the scope.

```
class Priverlidges {

    private $_state = false;

    public function canView($type, Scope $scope) {
        if(!$this->_state && $type & User::IS_ADMIN && in_array(User::IS_ADMIN, $scope->getPrivilidges())) {
            $this->_state = true;
        }

        if(!$this->_state && $type & User::IS_MODERATOR && in_array(User::IS_MODERATOR, $scope->getPrivilidges())) {
            $this->_state = true;
        }

        if(!$this->_state && $type & User::IS_MEMBER && in_array($scope->getPrivilidges(), User::IS_MEMBER)) {
            $this->_state = true;
        }

        return $this->_state;
    }

}
```